# Any example on how to integrate tokbox with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, opentok, tokbox

I am developing a simple app using ruby on rails framework. I would like to add a video conference to my app. I tried skype, hangouts...

I recently learned about this client tokbox.

Does anyone know it whether it can be integrated to ruby on rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You can use the [OpenTok JS SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/) to add real-time video to your application. You can find the sample applications on how to use the JS SDK with our Ruby SDK [here](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ruby-sdk).

Comment: Thanks for the information! Sorry for the dumb question. What is the difference between the information you have provided and the method given in this link: https://tokbox.com/developer/embeds/#creating

Comment: Also, I have one more question. I understand that a session is established and client1 and client 2 can publish their streams to the same session ID. Is there a way for client 1 to know the status or availability of other users. For example, if you open Facebook, there will status icon that is green next to the friends to indicate they are available to talk. Can this behavior be achieved in tokbox? Thanks

Comment: Embeds are a server-less video chatting solution, but it has limitations such as P2P, lack of customization, no archiving, etc. 

As for the available list, you can use the connectionCreated and connectionDestroyed event to know all the people connected to the session. For more info, please visit: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html